# Is it safe to marshal database objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, serialization, marshalling

I work with Ruby on Rails and want to cache some objects that I receive from the database. However, security is my priority and I am not sure if marshalling is the best choice over, for example, JSON.

Are there any security risks related to unmarshalling database objects? Is it possible to construct such an object that unmarshalling will result in remote code execution? If yes, how?

Comment: Think from another end: what do you think marshalling _gives_ you (over, say, JSON), except worries?

Comment: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Marshal.html#module-Marshal-label-Security+considerations

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks for the answer. I understand that database will store the user input in many cases. However, that data already validated and stored as something that maps to a certain data type. For example, could the unmarshalling of binary data column cause remote code execution? As I understand VARCHAR columns won't cause an issue, despite it depends on the implementation of marshaller. I do not want to follow the documentation blindly but measure the risk.

Comment: I don't understand. If security _is_ priority as you claim, why not go with the simpler, riskless formats?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev ok, I thought about it more, and attained enlightenment. Of course, I can store those objects and highly likely nothing will happen, but I know that this is a possible attack vector. So, I can avoid possible issues completely and not summon Murphy's laws upon me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I thought about it more, and attained enlightenment. Of course, I can store those objects and highly likely nothing will happen, but I know that this is a possible attack vector. So, I can avoid possible issues completely and not summon Murphy's laws upon me. Thanks to @SergioTulentsev for his patience!